# htaccess trouble rewriting language param

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble rewriting the subfolder back to the file.

**The redirect works but not the last rule.**

Here's what I'm trying to do:

`domain.com/file.php?lang=fr`

would like to rewrite it back to

`domain.com/fr/file.php`

no matter what folder the files are in.

I'm only using one language which is french.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ %1/$1.php?  [NS,R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.php/?$ $1.php?lang=fr&redirect=no [QSA,L]
```

---

my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /domain.com

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=([A-Za-z-]+)(/?$|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)redirect=noneed($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ %1/$1.php?  [NS,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.php/?$ http://localhost/?$1.php?lang=fr&redirect=noneed [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What problem do you get exactly?

Comment: @Alvin Wong i get a 404 error page. it redirects to `domain.com/fr/file.php` but it doesn't catch the page `domain.com/file.php?lang=fr`

Comment: `RewriteBase` isn't used like that. It's relative to the DocumentRoot. Change it back to `/`. (P.S. see my new comment)

Answer (score 0):

The 1st rule is more powerful then second, so to solve your issue you have to write second at 1st place.

Comment: In the OP's case it isn't because the `RewriteCond` *magically* fail when extra parameters are added to the query string!

Comment: i mean that `fr/file.php` suits the pattern `^(.*).php`, so the server redirects you to `fr/file.php` which is absent

Comment: No, the `RewriteCond` (`^lang=([A-Za-z-]+)/?$` isn't a match on the query string.

Comment: What if yout remove trailing slash in rewriteCond? `RewriteCond ^(lang=([A-Za-z-]+)?$` ?

Comment: The `&` in the new rewrited URL causes the unmatch, because `$` matches the *end*.

Comment: So your query string can be of any quantity of parameters? Then `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(lang=[A-Za-z]))?(&[a-z]+=[some pattern])*$` will check query with other parameters too.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a system like that:

```
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es)/(accueil|home|bienvenida)/$ /index.php?lang=$1&act=index[QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `RewriteBase` option:

```
RewriteRule On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([A-Za-z-]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ %1/$1.php?  [NS,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.php/?$ $1.php?lang=fr&redirect=no [QSA,L]
```

(or if you don't want that option append a `/` at the beginning of all paths)

Also, your `RewriteCond` doesn't *seem to* handle the query string correctly, any additional parameters will cause your first rule to fail. Do this instead (I am still thinking):

```
RewriteRule On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)lang=([A-Za-z-]+)(/?$|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)redirect=noneed($|&)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ %2/$1.php?  [NS,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.php/?$ $1.php?lang=fr&redirect=noneed [QSA,L]
```

Comment: the rewrite base is on. I tried the last code but still get an error page. When I try `domain.com/file.php?lang=fr` it redirects but strips the domain name now

Comment: @checkenginelight can you test if the `RewriteRule` is matched by adding the flag `R=403`? If the rule is matched you should get an 403 Forbidden

Comment: sorry not sure if I'm placing it in the right place.. i've updated what my current file looks like and the way it is now i get redirected to another one of my domains instead.

Comment: @checkenginelight I am also not sure, but I suggest you first try with the original one with the last rule changed to `RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)\.php/?$ http://localhost/?$1.php?lang=fr&redirect=no [QSA,L]`. Paste the final destination that you're redirected to.